# 'Undefined index: usertype' error for $_SESSION

Tags: php, laravel, session, routes

I get an error though I have set the session index in my Laravel project

> Undefined index: usertype

While user login I have set the `$_SESSION['usertype']` and redirect to `/home` url.

But I have got that error though set the session index.

**controller**

```
public function signin(Request $request)
{
    $username = $request->username;
    $password = md5($request->password);

    $exist = UserTbl::where('username','=', $username)->where('password','=', $password)->get();

    if(count($exist) > 0)
    {
        $_SESSION['usertype'] = $exist[0]->user_type;

        return redirect('/home');
    }
    else
    {
        return redirect('/');
    }
}
public function home()
{
    $_SESSION['active_menu'] = '1';
    return view('home');
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/home','PrescriptionController@home');
```

**View where I got the error**

```
@if($_SESSION['usertype'] == '1') // Got error in this line
                    <li>
                        <a href="{{ url('all-user') }}">
                            <span>All User</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="{{ url('create-user') }}">
                            <span>Create User</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                @endif
```

Comment: Use `isset()` function like this `@if(isset($_SESSION['usertype']) && $_SESSION['usertype'] == '1')`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Comment: if(count($exist) > 0)
    {
        $_SESSION['usertype'] = $exist[0]->user_type;
echo $_SESSION['usertype'] ; die;     //check the session usetype is setting or not...

Comment: @SayedMohdAli......I have already checked `$_SESSION['usertype']`...and it is set

Comment: @akshaypjoshi.....by using `@if(isset($_SESSION['usertype']) && $_SESSION['usertype'] == '1')` the error is solved but `li` is not still accessable. That means `isset` is true but `$_SESSION['usertype'] == '1'` is not true. But I set the value of $_SESSION['usertype'] to  '1'

Comment: Use Laravels Session class instead of accessing the session user global directly. I would also recommend getting the value from the session in the controller instead and just pass it to the view to keep the views as lean as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using laravel then you can simply user laravel session method as below,

```
//For set value in session

$request->session()->put('usertype',$exist[0]->user_type);

//For getting value from session

$request->session()->get('usertype');

//For getting session value in blade file

Session::get('usertype')
```

Comment: Not solved yet .... Error is not shown but my list item still doesn't show

Comment: check error log or possible post error if you found an error in log

Comment: Yes now it is correct....All of the answers are correct...But you give the first answer that's why i have accepted your answer

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple things to highlight in your question :

- You should use `Hash::` facade for passwords and not the simple `md5`
- The checked for login, you can use `Auth::attempt()` which also maintains the user session until user logs out or you call `Auth::logout()` See [this](https://justlaravel.com/custom-authentication-laravel/) blog post for knowing more about the same
- To deal with `sessions` in Laravel, laravel ships with different ways to manage [session](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/session) keys so you do not have to use `$_SESSION` directly. Like `$request->session()->get('usertype')` OR `session()->get('usertype')` OR `SESSION::get('usertype')`
- Also, it is a good practice before directly referring to a session key, is to check if it exists. Laravel's any session implementation comes with `has('key')` which returns boolean if the `key` you asked for exists in session or not.

For example :

```
@if(session()->has('usertype') &&  session()->get('usertype') == '1')
  ...
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

In your controller call `Session` Facade or use `$request->session()`. Here I use `Session` Facade.

```
use Session;

public function signin(Request $request)
{
    $username = $request->username;
    $password = md5($request->password);

    $exist = UserTbl::where('username','=', $username)->where('password','=', $password)->first();

    if(isset($exist->user_type))
    {
        Session::put('user_type') = $exist->user_type;

        return redirect('/home');
    }
    else
    {
        return redirect('/');
    }
}

public function home()
{
    Session::put('active_menu') = '1';
    return view('home');
}
```

**view**

```
@if(Session::get('user_type')==1)
                <li>
                    <a href="{{ url('all-user') }}">
                        <span>All User</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="{{ url('create-user') }}">
                        <span>Create User</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            @endif
```

Answer (score 1):

```
set session value
$request->session()->put('usertype', $exist[0]->user_type);

get session value 
@if(Session::get('variableName') == '1') // Got error in this line
                    <li>
                        <a href="{{ url('all-user') }}">
                            <span>All User</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="{{ url('create-user') }}">
                            <span>Create User</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                @endif
```